# Manually instantiating TestCase and add it to JUnit doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, testcase, test-suite

I need to reuse a TestCase, so I've created a private field "role" in my test case:

```
public class ATest extends TestCase {

    private String role;

    public void setRole(String userName) {
        role = userName;
    }

    @Test
    public void method1(){
        System.out.println("role:"+role);
    }
```

Now I want to create a suite with several testcases using the same "ATest" class:

```
public class AllTests {
    public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite(AllTests.class.getName());

        //CASE 1: Works fine
        suite.addTestSuite(ATest.class);

        //CASE 2: Doesn't work fName is null
        ATest aTest = new ATest();
        aTest.setRole("Admin");
        suite.addTest(aTest);

        //CASE 3: works but ugly
        ATest aTest2 = new ATest();
        aTest2.setName(aTest2.getClass().getMethods()[1].getName());
        aTest2.setRole("AnotherUser");
        suite.addTest(aTest2);

        return suite;
    }
}
```

The CASE 1 is the most obvious way to add a test case but doesn't enable to set my private field. The CASE 2 is what I want to do but doesn't work since the property fName of my test is null (I saw it using debug perspective in Eclipse). The last case CASE 3 seems to work but I don't want to use this approach.

Is there any more elegant and simple way to reuse the same test case ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a suite for this. You can use a parameterized class for this

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ATest { //with JUnit4, no need to extend from something
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {     
                 { "firstRole" }, { "SecondRole" }, { "ThirdRole" } 
           });
    }

    private final String role;

    public ATest(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("role:"+role);
    }
}
```

See the [JUnit wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) for more information on parameterized tests.